# Trouble with d3 line charts with points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

So I guess my main issue is that my data isn't EXACTLY like all of the d3 demos out there.  I made a plugin that normalizes all my data into the form:

```
[{"name":"someName", "values":[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ... {xn, yn}, ...]
```

So this code works just fine for the line:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

// data is a list of objects, each of which respresents a line
var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
    .data(dataSimplified)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "series");

series.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    // the following function requires a list of things, like [{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}, ... {xn, yn}]
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

So it basically iterates over each "values" field and does the line function to get the x and y.  But if I do a similar thing for the points, it doesn't work!  The following, however, DOES work:

```
// add points
for(var i=0; i<dataSimplified.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<dataSimplified[i].values.length; j++){
        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 3.5)
            .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(dataSimplified[i].values[j].x); })
            .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(dataSimplified[i].values[j].y); })
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(dataSimplified[i].name); });
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this than adding the points one by one?  Why doesn't cx accept a list like d did for the path?

Comment: You want [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `.data` again on for [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) (in this case the `<circle>` tags nested inside the `<g>` tag). Something like this:

```
series.selectAll('circle')
    .data(function(d, i, j) { return d.values; })
    .enter().append('circle')
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(nd){ return x(nd.x); })
        .attr("cy", function(nd){ return y(nd.y); })
        .attr("fill", function(nd, i, j){ return color(dataSimplified[j].name); });
```

The reason it seems inconsistent between line and circle is that D3 is only a thin layer over the underlying DOM nodes (html or svg), and doesn't abstract that away from you. So in svg, `<path>` is a single tag which contains an internal list of points, while `<circle>` is just one circle. So your structure for one series will be something like this (assuming you have three data points).

```
<g><path/><circle/><circle/><circle/></g>
```

And so your code will reflect the same kind of structure.

Comment: Thank you, that looks much better than a nested for loop!  I'm going to have to try to better understand what .data means with a function and what .enter() means.  Coming from a jquery world it looks nonsensical, select all circles (that don't exist) and set some data function, call enter() and then append a circle?  It's weird.

Comment: It does look odd for just the append, but the structure is powerful as you eventually move on to data changes and want to control the exact animations for edited vs. removed items.